# The total area of all land cover data exceeds the corresponding polygon area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am using the national land cover raster data. I have an MSA boundary shapefile.  I want to calculate the area of each land cover within each MSA area. So I used the Tabulate Area tool in ArcGIS Pro to calculate it. But I found for each MSA, the total area of all land cover exceeds the MSA area.

Can someone help me with it?

The resolution of the MSA shapefile is 1:500,000.
the resolution of land cover data is 30 meters.

I have set the cell size to be consistent with the land cover data. But still, I have this problem.

Comment: `1:500,000` is not really a resolution, it's a scale, and it's unit-less. On the opposite, a resolution is expressed in ground-meter per pixel. Therefore, you miss an information to bridge the gap. In addition, can you precise the projection system of both your input data? Because if your results are given, e.g., in degrees and you want to compare them with meters, you will definitely have to reproject one or the other so that everything fits in the [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I reprojected my boundary map to be consistent with my raster map. And I found the total area calculated is still not exactly the same as the one in the boundary map. I guess this is probably due to the measurement error. Thank you again!